# Drupal Commerce: product deleted resurrect after a while

Tags: commerce

I have a Commerce Kickstart 2 installation.

This is really weird and I can't understand. I'm deleting a product in manage products page. I confirm the deletion, but after a while when I search for that product, it mysteriously resurrects and is displayed in the search in manage products page.

Anybody could help me? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Does it have the same ID in the database? What do you see if you look in MySQL after deleting it? Have you cleared caches? What are you using for search?

Comment: I haven't looked yet if the product was really removed from database. Now I deleted the product again, and checked in mysql if the product has been gone. It was deleted. Now I have to wait to see if the product magically come back. Have cleared the caches and I'm doing search in manage products. I've checked also by ID before delete and the ID (SKU) was the same in manage products search and in database.

Comment: What are you using for search? How often is your search index updated?

Comment: I make the search in Manage products page. Searching by Title or SKU. As you mention the search index updating, it is possible that the search index isn't updated fast enough and the product that I've been removed come back in search results. I will check that. Sorry for comment delay. Thanks @beth.